# How to handle return value of snippet() in SQLite with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I can't work out how to access the returned value of a snippet() search in SQLite. If I search like this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM guidelines WHERE guidelines MATCH '" + search + "*';";
```

Then I get an object with values corresponding to column names that I can access easily. This prints out the correct values:

```
$('#lbResult').append('<br/> Search result:' + row.category + ' ' + row.id + ' ' + row.header + '<br/>');
```

But if I search with the snippet() function, like this:

```
query = "SELECT snippet(guidelines) FROM guidelines WHERE guidelines MATCH '" + search + "*';";
```

And then try to print the result like this:

```
transaction.executeSql(query,[], function(transaction, result) {
                    if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                        $('#lbResult').html('');
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                            var row = result.rows.item(i);
                            $('#lbResult').append('<br/> ' + row);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Then I get an Object Object for each returned result. I'm getting the correct number of returned results, so the search is working, I just don't know how to target this value in JavaScript. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I searched high & low for an answer to this one. In the end I got it by running `for key in (object)` loops for various levels of the returned object, which turned out to work for `item`:

```
  transaction.executeSql(query,[], function(transaction, result) {

                    if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                        $('#lbResult').html('');

                        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                            var row = result.rows.item(i);

                            for(var key in row) {
                                var value = row[key]; //this gives the string value of the returned snippet
                                $('#lbResult').append('<br/> ' + value );
                            }
                        }
                    }

                },nullHandler,errorHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

The column name `snippet(guidelines)` cannot be used as a name in JavaScript.

You could retrieve the column value by its index in the row, but the code is clearer if you give the column another name:

```
query = "SELECT snippet(guidelines) AS snips FROM ..:";
... 
value = row.snips;
```